# tkinter text line spacing

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Is there a way to fractionally increase the spacing of lines in a tkinter text widget?

I'd like to space my text at, say, 1.2 * font size to enable the user to adjust for readability.

The spacing1, spacing2 and spacing3 parameters appear to be platform dependent, not supported on Windows, and whole lines only.

Comment: The `spacing1`, `spacing2`, and `spacing3` options are the only way to affect the spacing of lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure spacing in pixels as follows:

```
text.config(spacing1=10)    # Spacing above the first line in a block of text
text.config(spacing2=10)    # Spacing between the lines in a block of text
text.config(spacing3=10)    # Spacing after the last line in a block of text
```

Works for me on Python 3.6.5 on win10. Or do you have an example of non-working code?