# python tkinter add spacing to label with multiple lines

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using tkinter with python 3.9.10.

I have a label which include multiple lines. The spacing between the lines is very narrow and I'm trying to increase it.
will appreciate and suggestion.

My code:

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.geometry(window_size)
window.title("Terpi App")
label = Label(window, text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. \n"
                       "Nam posuere mi sit amet dolor eleifend, nec dignissim enim volutpat\n"
                       "Morbi ut facilisis magna, ut scelerisque dolor. \n"
                       "Mauris non nulla mi.", font=("ariel", 20), justify="left")
label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="center")
window.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: A Label has very limited options for formatting - about all you could do is double (or triple, etc.) the newline characters, but that's likely too big of an increase in line spacing.  The option is to use a Text widget instead, which has precise control over line spacing - and then set it to read-only mode.

Comment: Split the message into lines and use labels to show those lines inside a frame, then you can set the padding (`pady`) you want between labels.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65135455/tkinter-text-line-spacing